# How to get numbers to words conversion using cash_words function in indian currency format in postgres

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I am using cash_words('100');
It is showing **one hundred dollars and zero cents** but i want **one hundred rupees** as output using cash_words only
For that i used lc_monetary ='en_IN.UTF-8' but no use any other parameters need to change

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data?. E.g. in form of [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com).

Comment: in dbfiddle it is showing error error: function cash_words(numeric) does not exist

Comment: Try looking here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089454/i-want-a-postgresql-function-to-get-amount-in-words-with-fils

Comment: ok, i am currently using above one but can i get using cash_words() in indian format

Answer (score 1):

Can use the below script:

SELECT replace(cash_words('100'), 'dollars and zero cents', 'rupees');

This will give the following output:

One hundred rupees

Basically, we replace the dollars and zero cents text that is appended by the cash_words function with custom text. It can also be set to blank i.e '' if you do not want anything to be appended after the converted words.